# How to access string object in array of JSON-array via PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have searched for almost 30 minutes and still can't find the answer for my problem.
So, here is it: 
I have an JSON-file called "localeDE.l", now I'm trying to print the objects to the website, "locale_name"(type: string) works, but "translations"(type: array) won't work.

My JSON file:

```
"locale_name": "DE",
"translations": [
    {"Welcome": "Willkommen",
     "Goodbye": "Auf Wiedersehen"}
]
```

Here my PHP file:

```
$file = file_get_contents('localeDE.l');
$locale = json_decode($file);
print_r($locale);
echo "Locale=" . $locale->{'locale_name'};
echo "Translations:";
echo "  Welcome:" . $locale->{'translations'}->{'Welcome'};
echo "  Goodbye:" . $locale->{'translations'}->{'Goodbye'};
```

I also tried something like `(...) $locale->{'translations.Welcome'};` etc.
Can You help me?

- Felipe Kaiser

Comment: json_decode() returns an array, not an object. `$local['translations']['Welcome']`

Comment: Erm..sorry! Oversaw `mixed` at php.net^^ Thank You!

Comment: //Edit: This doesn't work..

Comment: `var_dump($locale)`, then. look at what got produced.

Comment: If that is your whole json then it is not a valid.

Comment: @frz3993 Yes my WebBrowser actually didn't registered/sent the braces..

Answer (score 1):

First the JSON like you typed it here is incomplete. It's missing both opening and closing curly braces.

It should be

```
{"locale_name": "DE",
 "translations": [
     {"Welcome": "Willkommen",
     "Goodbye": "Auf Wiedersehen"}
]}
```

The php to read it

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
//to read the locale name
echo $obj['locale_name'];
//to read the translation of welcome
echo $obj['tranlations'][0]['Welcome'];
//to read the tranlation of goodbye
echo $obj['translations'][0]['Goodbye'];
```

Cheers.

Comment: @Makville: Sorry but I get this error:`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\API\debug.php on line 7`

Comment: Try replacing json_decode($json); with json_decode($json, true);

Answer (score 1):

## Figured it out!

Now I figured it out how it works! Thanks alot to you!

### Additionals

Here are my code pieces:

```
$json = file_get_contents('localeDE.l');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
echo $obj['locale_name'];
echo $obj['translations'][0]['Welcome'];
echo $obj['translations'][0]['Goodbye'];
```

And my JSON file is unrelevant, for those who are interested, see the answer of Makville above.

Thanks alot! :)